# HttpPost Route breaking Mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a three tier view path which I am trying to route and map.

```
[Route("parent", Name = "parent")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Parent", ParentKey = "home", Key = "parent")]
public ActionResult parent()
{
    ...............
}

[Route("parent/child/{param}", Name = "child")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Child", ParentKey = "parent", Key = "child", PreservedRouteParameters = "param")] 
public ActionResult child(int param)
{
    ..............
}

[Route("parent/child/{param}/{filterparam1 ?}/{filterparam2 ?}")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult child(int param, int filterparam1 = 0, int filterparam2 = 0 )
{
    ..............
}

[Route("parent/child/grandchild/{param}/{name}")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Grandchild", ParentKey = "child", Key="grandchild", PreservedRouteParameters = "param, name")]
public ActionResult grandchild(int param, string = name)
{
    ..............

    var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
    node.Title = model.name;

    ..............
}
```

The problem I have is that if I include the [Route] tag on the [HttpPost]:

```
[Route("parent/child/{param}/{filterparam1 ?}/{filterparam2 ?}")]
[HttpPost]
```

My postback filter works, but the grandchild does not get included in the routing tree, does not show on my breadcrumb and the node code Errors:

```
var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
node.Title = model.name;
```

If however I comment out the [Routing] tag on the [HttpPost] the filter does not work but the grandchild does get routed, appears on my breadcrumb and the node code runs successfully.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out for anyone with the same problem:

I reordered the code in the controller so that all named route came before any posts:

```
[Route("parent/child/{param}", Name = "child")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Child", ParentKey = "parent", Key = "child", PreservedRouteParameters = "param")] 
public ActionResult child(int param)
{
    ..............
}

[Route("parent/child/grandchild/{param}/{name}")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Grandchild", ParentKey = "child", Key="grandchild", PreservedRouteParameters = "param, name")]
public ActionResult grandchild(int param, string = name)
{
    ..............

    var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
    node.Title = model.name;

    ..............
}

[Route("parent/child/{param}/{filterparam1 ?}/{filterparam2 ?}")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult child(int param, int filterparam1 = 0, int filterparam2 = 0 )
{
    ..............
}
```